# Google cloud storage lifecycle configuration filesize?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've been trying to implement lifecycle management to objects I store in my GCP storage with no overall success.

First of all I have a bucket that stores objects per date. (intermediate & files of pipeline runs) So I want to retain, say maybe 10 days past, but then I want to move to more archived uses.

So on this storage bucket I've created the following lifecycle.json:

```
{
   "lifecycle":{
      "rule":[
         {
            "action":{
               "type":"SetStorageClass",
               "storageClass":"NEARLINE"
            },
            "condition":{
               "age":3,
               "matchesStorageClass":[
                   "REGIONAL",                  
                  "STANDARD",
                  "DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "action":{
               "type":"SetStorageClass",
               "storageClass":"COLDLINE"
            },
            "condition":{
               "age":10,
               "matchesStorageClass":[
                  "NEARLINE"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "action":{
               "type":"Delete"
            },
            "condition":{
               "age":10,
               "matchesStorageClass":[
                  "COLDLINE"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Based on this manual: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#enable

When I set the lifecycle using gsutil it accepts it, and when I get it it shows it.

But not all files seem to be affected by the configuration and I'm having this theory that it depends on filesize, e.g. 
[image: sizesstorage]

All files were uploaded on the same exact day (with 1 hour window). but only some are nearline, some are still regional. In this directory the tipping point is around 100MB, but in another a 300MB+ file makes it into nearline

[image: large]

My questions:

- How do I make this consistent?
- Are some of the files still being processed perhaps?
- Can I monitor this process anywhere?
- If skipped now, how do I retrigger for those files, because I still have files in this bucket that are +1GB in size, but more than 23 days old and still present in the regional bucket

**--- 
Update 20170720
---**

As per requested I've ran the command:

`gsutil ls -L gs://yourbucket`

One large csv file, which should be removed by now:

```
Creation time:          Tue, 27 Jun 2017 12:23:08 GMT
Update time:            Tue, 27 Jun 2017 12:23:08 GMT
Storage class:          REGIONAL
Content-Length:         1184976409
Content-Type:           text/csv
Component-Count:        23
Hash (crc32c):          ggHfjw==
ETag:                   COqC4oqC3tQCEAE=
Generation:             1498566188630378
Metageneration:         1
```

The directory of files from the screenshot has been processed and everything was deleted below a certain filesize:

The files remaining should also have been deleted:

```
Creation time:          Sat, 08 Jul 2017 10:00:57 GMT
Update time:            Sat, 08 Jul 2017 10:00:57 GMT
Storage class:          REGIONAL
Content-Length:         469342393
Content-Type:           application/octet-stream
Component-Count:        9
Hash (crc32c):          Ux3HKw==
ETag:                   COLb3ei2+dQCEAE=
Generation:             1499508057271778
Metageneration:         1
ACL:                    [
```

So we can rule out the fact that the file was modified in the mean time.

Comment: Note that the browser screenshot you're showing is displaying "Last modified", which comes from the `updated` timestamp field. Lifecycle uses the `timeCreated` timestamp field for the `Age` condition. Can you run `gsutil ls -L gs://yourbucket` and confirm that `timeCreated` is what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed in the mean time